# A notation for a morphism in a thin category

Tags: notation, category-theory, order-theory, abstract-algebra

Consider a thin category with objects $A\leq B$. There exists a unique morphism $A\rightarrow B$.

Is there a standard notation for this morphism (given $A$ and $B$)?

Comment: Maybe $(A,B)$ would be a suitable notation?

Answer (score 3):

Note that a thin category is nothing else than a $\{0,1\}$-enriched category. If we interpret $0$ as "false" and $1$ as "true", then a morphism $A \to B$ can be identified with the truth value of $A \leq B$. Hence, $A \leq B$ is a good notation for this unique morphism $A \to B$, and it coincides with the usual meaning.

Answer (score 2):

"$A \leq B$" is a pretty good name for it.

By analogy with posets of open sets in topological spaces, $i_{A,B}$ is good too.

Comment: It isn't $A\leq B$ is a logical formula and can take only two values: false or true. The set of all morphisms may have more than 2 members what makes this notation contradictory

Comment: Unless, of course I use phrase "$A \leq B$", when clear from context, to mean the homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard terminology for that, nor is there *any* terminology at all for that morphism. The category $Pos$ of posets is equivalent to the category of (small) categories with at most one morphisms between any two objects, but the categories are not isomorphic nor is there a canonical equivalence between the two categories. This is basically the situation you are describing. The reason there isn't any particular terminology for that morphism is that it is a lot more convenient to refer simply to $A\le B$ and leave the name of the morphism implicit. Which equivalence one chooses has no practical implications, and introducing *any* notation for the implicit morphism will only serve to clutter the notation.

Comment: But the category of *preorders* is (canonically) isomorphic to the category of thin small categories.